# I remove a file that I uploaded, I got a error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

When I remove a file that I uploaded, I got a error. That is `js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null`. I have to use `removeChild` and `var` for IE. Is there a good way to fix the error?

- html

```
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="page_form">
          <label class="ui_upload upload_label" for="upload-doc">

            <input type="file" name="file" id="upload-doc"
              accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
              multiple />
            <span class="btn sm label upload_btn">upload file</span>
          </label>
          <div class="upload_documents_wrap visually_hide">
            <div class="upload_documents"> </div>
          </div>

          <div class="visually_hide" id="upload-file">
            <div class="upload_info shadow light upload_file">
              <span class="tit sm file_name"> </span>
              <span class="tit sm file_size"> </span>
              <button class="file_remove" type="button">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn sm">submit</button>
        </form>
```

- js

```
(function () {
  var formElement = document.querySelector(".page_form");
  var fileChooserEl = formElement.querySelector('.upload_label input[type="file"]');
  var uploadDocumentsWrap = formElement.querySelector(".upload_documents_wrap");
  var uploadDocuments = uploadDocumentsWrap.querySelector(".upload_documents");
  var templateItemParent = document.querySelector("#upload-file");
  var templateItem = templateItemParent.querySelector(".upload_file");
  var uploadFiles = [];
  var myFileList = [];

  var onFileChooserChange = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < fileChooserEl.files.length; i++) {
      var position = templateItem.cloneNode(true);
      var uploadFileName = position.querySelector(".file_name");
      var uploadFileSize = position.querySelector(".file_size");
      var uploadFileRemove = position.querySelector(".file_remove");
      var fileName = fileChooserEl.files[i].name.toLowerCase();
      uploadDocumentsWrap.classList.remove("visually_hide");
      uploadFileName.textContent = fileName; // file size

      var suffix = "bytes";
      var size = fileChooserEl.files[i].size;

      if (size >= 1024 && size < 1024000) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size = Math.round(size / 1024 * 100) / 100;
      } else if (size >= 1024000) {
        suffix = "MB";
        size = Math.round(size / 1024000 * 100) / 100;
      }

      uploadFileSize.textContent = size + suffix;
      uploadFileRemove.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        myFileList = myFileList.filter(function (item) {
          return item.name.toLowerCase() !== uploadFileRemove.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        });
        console.log(myFileList);
        var index = uploadFiles.indexOf(evt.target.parentNode);
        uploadFileRemove.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(uploadFileRemove.parentNode);
        uploadFiles.splice(index, 1);
        myFileList.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(index);

        if (!uploadFiles.length) {
          uploadDocumentsWrap.classList.add("visually_hide");
        }
      });
      uploadDocuments.appendChild(position);
      uploadFiles.push(position);
      myFileList.push(fileChooserEl.files[i]);
    }

    fileChooserEl.value = "";
  };

  console.log(uploadFiles);

  var getFormData = function () {
    var data = new FormData(formElement);

    for (var i = 0; i < myFileList.length; i += 1) {
      data.append(fileChooserEl.name, myFileList[i]);
    }

    return data;
  };

  fileChooserEl.addEventListener("change", onFileChooserChange);
})();
```

Comment: Can your code work in IE? I made a test and it can't work in IE because `for...of` [doesn't support IE 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#browser_compatibility). It shows `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'` in IE 11. You need to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the code. The error in your question shows in Chrome. So do you want to deal with the error in Chrome?

Comment: @YuZhou Yes. I want to fix the error in Chrome. And I use babel polyfill for IE. If I got a new error in IE, it is next step after fixing in Chrome, I think.

Comment: @YuZhou I fixed the error ```for...of``` in IE what you wrote. But I still couldn't fix the error in Chrome that is ```js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null```. Do you know how to work it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
uploadFileRemove.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(uploadFileRemove.parentNode);
```

I debugged the code and find that you removed wrong file every time when clicking the "Remove" button. It's easier and more clear to identify which file to remove using `index`. I edit the code like this and it works well:

```
...
var index = uploadFiles.indexOf(evt.target.parentNode);
//edit
var removefile = document.querySelectorAll(".upload_info")[index];
uploadDocuments.removeChild(removefile);                      
//uploadFileRemove.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(uploadFileRemove.parentNode);
uploadFiles.splice(index, 1);
myFileList.splice(index, 1);
console.log(index);
...
```

Result:

[image]